# Is it bad design to use one table to hold COUNT/SUM's of another larger table?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm in the middle of making a fantasy betting league application in PHP/MySQL and I have two tables:

**Achievements** - which currently holds the players all-time achievements with the following columns:

```
user_id
total_gold_medals
total_silver_medals
total_bronze_medals
total_bets
total_winnings
```

**Bets** - Which is a list of each individual bet placed by each user, if that bet was awarded a medal, and how much winnings if any were received.

```
date_placed
user_id
winnings
gold_medal
silver_medal
bronze_medal
```

Now, as the predictions are based on live events the results can change sometimes so I don't want to increment the `achievements` table until 2 weeks has passed.

Currently, the reason for me having two tables for similar data is because I don't want to query and COUNT/SUM from an ever growing `bets` table when I only need a small part of that database for the current week.

95% of the time I'll be using only the data in the `achievements` table, so my initial thought was to move the data from `bets` to `achievements` after 2 weeks has passed, and mark them bets as 'archived' with a new `archived` field so they aren't included in any further SUM()'s. This method of keeping the data in two places seems like a very clumsy way of doing things though. Should I be doing things differently, a different table structure maybe? How would you go about this?

Comment: Usually. Yes. It's a bad idea.

Comment: @Strawberry: I disagree. Cache tables aren't bad if managed properly. It depends on the use of the database. Data warehouses uses the kinds of tables all the time because normalization is much less important. An OLTP system probably should be more judicious.

Comment: @Strawberry do you think that any serious bank in the world keeps only the deposits/withdrawals/interests of the money accounts - without storing the current balance?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you're trying to achieve. In principle, the need to the achievements table is not clear as it can be calculated (count, sum) from the bets table. If `bets` has timestamps, not taking the last two weeks into account can easily be achieved.

If performance is your concern then creating a secondary table for totals, a so-called aggregation table (some DBs call it a materialized view) may be one valid approach.

I would however strongly recommend building performance optimizations if and only when the application logic is stable and performance problems become foreseeable.

PS.: I would however question the use of silver, bronze, gold columns and instead introduce a (numeric) type column for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks. The main reason was for performance yes. The main page of the application is a rankings table including winnings that week & medals and winnings total, would it be fine querying one table when bets gets to 1-2 million rows?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect use case for an external cache like [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [Memcached](http://memcached.org/).

The idea would be to write the expensive query in MySQL that calculates the counts and sums for medals/winnings/bets - even if it's slow.

Then you run the query and put the results into Redis or Memcached. Have your application look at the cache instead of MySQL.

Benefits:

1. Redis and Memcached store their data purely in RAM, so the queries will be *very* fast.
2. If you are doing enough queries from your database you will need a cache in the future anyways. It's a standard part of web architectures these days.
3. It takes care of the denormalizing fears you mentioned. In other words, the data won't be copied somewhere else in MySQL.
4. It definitely protectes your database from heavy loads.

As a final recommendation, if your bets table gets around 20 million rows, then I would think about trimming it/running a job to move out old rows.

Otherwise MySQL should handle queries up to that point just fine.